# Orthographic hyphenation word in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

Is there a way of orthographic hyphenation word?

Something like this:

```
NSStiring *string = @"In June 2010 at the World Wide Developers Conference, Apple announced version 4 of Xcode during the Developer Tools State of the Union address.";
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = string;
```

And if frame UILabel will be narrow, get next:

> In June 2010 at
>   the World Wide
>   Developers Con-
>   ference, Apple
>   announced ver-
>   sion 4 of Xcode
>   during the Devel-
>   oper Tools State
>   of the Union ad-
>   dress.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use an NSAttributedString with an NSParagraphStyle with a `hyphenationFactor` of 1.

Answer (score 6):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *string = @"In June 2010 at the World Wide Developers Conference, Apple announced version 4 of Xcode during the Developer Tools State of the Union address.";
NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0;
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

**Swift 4**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle])
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Swift 3**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle])
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. Please Change Uilabel Text plain to Attributed  I tried Xcode 7+[image]