# UILabel: wrap and/or break inside word(s) with hyphen(s)

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap, hyphenation, nsparagraphstyle

How do I set a UILabel lineBreakMode to break words and add hyphens to broken words?

> a label with a broken wo-
>
> rd should look like this

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Elaborating on Matt's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502598/196358 it can be done using NSAttributedString and NSParagraphStyle. See below:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0f;
    
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleString attributes:@{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle }];
    
self.titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

This will cause the label to break at logical places mid-word using hyphens. It looks great, and is pretty simple to do. It requires iOS 6.0, but I've only tried it under 7.0.

> **WARNING:** Font, Color, Alignment --- basically nothing is inherited by attributed-text's render from it's hosting and/or owner `UILabel` (you need to add those attributes manually).

Comment: I needed a little more. From Apple doc, "hyphenationFactor valid values lie between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive". I lowered the value to increase the resistance to hyphens.

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 5.0**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0

let hyphenAttribute = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: hyphenAttribute)
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0

let hyphenAttribute = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
    ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: hyphenAttribute)
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: “Your String”, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle])
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**From Storyboard**

[image]

Comment: To be noted, one does not need to specify paragraph style and hyphenation factor if text contains a soft-hyphen.

Comment: To center align, add `paragraphStyle.alignment = .center` to it.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it's crucial to add a `locale` attribute key.

```
NSString *lorem = @"Lorem ipsum <et cetera>.";

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.hyphenationFactor = 1;
paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

self.label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lorem attributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor darkGrayColor],
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph,
    @"locale": @"la", // Latin, use @"en-US" for American English, for example.
}];
```

Comment: Is "locale" documented somewhere as a valid attribute name for `NSAttributedString`? There is also an "NSLanguage" attribute, i.e. `kCTLanguageAttributeName`, which is documented in the CoreText header as follows: _Value must be a CFStringRef containing a locale identifier. Default is unset. When this attribute is set to a valid identifier, it will be used to select localized glyphs (if supported by the font) and locale-specific line breaking rules._

Comment: I have never tested an `NSLanguage` attribute and never seen any documentation for `@"locale"`, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't delete this as it was accepted, but I am wrong from today's POV.

EARLIER UILabel did not offer Hyphenation.
TODAY it does through NSAttributedString (ios6+)

see: [Orthographic hyphenation word in IOS 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502556/orthographic-hyphenation-word-in-ios-6-x/16502598#16502598)

Comment: Are you familiar with any UILabel extensions that add this functionality?

Comment: UILabel now supports hyphenation using NSAttributedStrings.

Comment: Who put - sings to this answer are bad people

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. please Change Uilabel Text plain to Attributed
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
class AttributedStrings {
    private func paragraphStyle(alignment: NSTextAlignment, hyphenate: Bool) -> NSMutableParagraphStyle {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.hyphenationFactor = hyphenate ? 0.1 : 0
        style.alignment = alignment
        return style
    }
    
    func string(_ string: String, font: UIFont, color: UIColor, alignment: NSTextAlignment = .left, hyphenate: Bool = true) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle(alignment: alignment, hyphenate: hyphenate)
        ]
        return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
    }
}

let attributedStrings = AttributedStrings()
let attributedString1 = attributedStrings.string("Hyphenate this", font: .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24), color: .black)
let attributedString2 = attributedStrings.string("Don't hyphenate this", font: .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24), color: .black, hyphenate: false)
let attributedString3 = attributedStrings.string("Center and hyphenate this", font: .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24), color: .black, alignment: .center)

let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = attributedString1
```

Since we can't subclass `NSAttributedString`, consider making a vendor class that makes them for you. The key difference with my answer is the hyphenation factor. Hyphenation factor is a float between `0.0` and `1.0`. A factor of `1.0` will always hyphenate the word no matter what. A factor of `0.1` will only hyphenate the word if there isn't enough room on the next line to display it without hyphenation. But you can play with the factor to find a threshold that you like.