# Justify text for UILabel in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, ios9, justify

I have found solution to justify text in UILabel for versions up to iOS 8.4 through attributed strings: set label string as attributed and modify hyphenation value as presented below. 
[image]

This solution stopped working on iOS 9 (text shows left aligned). I need other working solution which supports from iOS 7 or at least works at iOS 9 (would add 'if' somewhere)

Comment: Maybe it got removed because typographically it is considered bad practice to justify line endings.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` works from ios 7, you could get more from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)

Comment: @NghiaLuong, it is attributted at working build, but justification doesn't work anymore on iOS 9. Does it work this way only for me?

Comment: @NghiaLuong, reading your link gave me an idea to convert my labels to textViews which allow to justify text right from nib. It is not quick fix, but at least it works. Thanks! BTW, anyone who want UITextView to automatically calculate its intrinsicSize (autolayout) - turn off scrolling

Answer (score -1):

#### Update:

It seems that adding a `@"locale"` key to attributes of `NSAttributedString` may help. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39374137/826716).

#### Original answer:

You can always use `NSAttributedString` here:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody],
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
};

NSString *string = @"your text here";

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];

self.label.attributedText = attributedString;
self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: I use attributted string as provided in screenshot. Only difference is that I did that in XIB, not in code. But as I mentioned in questions - it doesn't work in iOS 9. It shows as left aligned

Comment: @PooLaS Interesting that when I supply text in my local language – Russian – it appears justified and hyphenated, but in English it's left-aligned and non-hyphenated.