# How to add - in the label in ios swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a multi-line label and when the label go to new line i want to get - in the end of line. i am doing it programmatically. How to achieve that?
i already try this but its not working

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping 
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

In this case label become multiline but - is not added at the end of the line.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is not proper, please add further details like whther you are using storyboard or doing by code and what you'r getting as a output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to get hyphenated text, as in:

```
This is a hyphen-
ated word wrap.
```

Take a look here: [add hyphens on word break in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979545/add-hyphens-on-word-break-in-a-uilabel)

Answer (score -2):

Above code is working good Try this code just increase the height of the label and width also increased.

[image]

```
 @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelText.text = "if you know C or Objective-C then you might be familiar with Enums and Structs.However,if you don’t know either of those languages then you are probably"
    labelText.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelText.numberOfLines = 0
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP wants - at end of each line break

Comment: i already tried this one its not working