# UILabel: "opposite" of non breaking space? I.e. show where a word can be hyphenated

Tags: ios, uilabel

I need to mark occurrences in words where it can be hyphenated if there's not enough rough, e.g.

```
loremip|sum
```

so if there's enough room, it should show `loremipsum` if not, it should be `loremip-` on the first line, `sum` on the second.

Bonus point: if the character is ignored by search, i.e. searching for `loremips` would find that occurrence. Does something like that exist on iOS?

Using `NSParagraphStyle` isn't enough as it splits the words at points where it isn't allowed (note: I'm using german). Also I would like to use words not really common as they are dialect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979545/add-hyphens-on-word-break-in-a-uilabel

Your need is similar to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add hyphens on word break in a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979545/add-hyphens-on-word-break-in-a-uilabel)

Comment: please see my edit