# Line break in other ways than `NSLineBreakMode` offers (with Core Text?)

Tags: ios, layout, line-breaks, core-text, typesetting

I'm creating an application where users are able to change the font and size of certain texts. This makes layout kind of hard. However I've got some predefined texts and I don't like the way they're broken down to lines sometimes.

For example, a text might be: "• Midsommardagen", which might be broken down to what's shown in the image provided.

[image]

I think that's ugly and would rather break it down to:

```
• Midsommar-
dagen
```

As that's more visually pleasing and fit's better with the Swedish language ("Midsummer day").

What's the best approach to this? Core Text? Any tips on how to realise it with Core Text?

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979545/add-hyphens-on-word-break-in-a-uilabel

Comment: Wasn’t exactly what I wanted? But seems to solve the problem in a easy to implement way! :) now I just need to know if I I can change language (instead of using preferred)

Comment: Because the pdf can be generated for a language that is not the same as those in preferred