# UITextView word-wrap like Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios

I have the following Android TextView:

```
<TextView
    fontPath="fonts/Ubuntu-Light.ttf"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Moyennement"
    android:id="@+id/txt_score2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:textColor="@color/indicator_score_text" />
```

And a corresponding iOS UITextView (code):

```
var smiley = new UITextView { Text = name, ScrollEnabled = false, Font = FontHelpers.GenerateUIFont("Ubuntu-Light", 8), };
smiley.TextContainer.MaximumNumberOfLines = 2;
smiley.TextContainer.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.CharacterWrap;
smiley.SizeToFit();
```

On iOS, it gives me the following result:

[image]

But on Android, the text "Moyennement" that does not fit is correctly truncated:

[image]

What Am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979545/add-hyphens-on-word-break-in-a-uilabel - or search for `hyphenationFactor` in the Apple documentation

Comment: This allowed me to have the hypen but the text stops at it, can't see the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is a mix of Andreas Oetjen's suggestion and the use of a UILabel instead of a UITextView.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
paragraphStyle.HyphenationFactor = 1.0f;
var hyphenAttribute = new UIStringAttributes();
hyphenAttribute.ParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle;
var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(str: name, attributes: hyphenAttribute);
var smiley = new UILabel { AttributedText = attributedString, Font = FontHelpers.GenerateUIFont("Ubuntu-Light", 10), TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false };
smiley.Lines = 2;
smiley.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
```

LineBreakMode is no more used as it is conflicting with HyphenationFactor. This would probably work with a UITextView as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<TextView
    fontPath="fonts/Ubuntu-Light.ttf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Moyenne-\nment"
    android:id="@+id/txt_score2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:textColor="@color/indicator_score_text" />
```

Comment: Android is fine ;)

Comment: My question is about iOS not Android.